# How can I view my HTML webpage in a mobile emulator and make my code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

```js
var Person= {}; 

Person.Character= function(firstName, lastName, gender, age) 
{ 
    this.FirstName= firstName;
    this.LastName= lastName;
    this.Gender= gender; 
    this.Age= age;  
} 

Person.Character.prototype.GetAllInformation= function() 
{
      return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName + " "  + this.Gender + " "  + 
       + this.Age;   
}

Person.Zack = new Person.Character("Zack", "Efron", "Male", 29); 
Person.Shia = new Person.Character("Shia", "Labeouf","Male", 30);  


document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = Person.Zack.GetAllInformation(); 

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = Person.Shia.GetAllInformation();
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
    #demo1{ width: 100px;} 
    #demo2{ width: 100px;}
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example-style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id= "demo1"></p>
<p id= "demo2"></p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Everyone,

I have created a webpage and used CSS to handle media queries so when I view my webpage on a mobile emulator, it will become active when I reduce the width size of the screen or when the screen is turned to portrait form. So basically I want to know how I can view HTML my page on the emulator (it doesn't see to work with on this website(http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/)) and if I am doing my media queries right? I know they are right so far, but is there a way that I can combine the two media queries into one media query? This would then reduce the code I have in CSS. I have attached the code I have done so far in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for anyone's viewing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain media query paramaters!

**For example:**

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    #demo1{ width: 100px;} 
    #demo2{ width: 100px;}
}
```

In your case, your media query would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
    #demo1{ width: 100px;} 
    #demo2{ width: 100px;}
    body { background-color: red; }
}
```

---

**@Robert I**'s answer has all the information you need for testing responsive web design - I'm not going to repost it.

Comment: @Zze-So the CSS is fine for what I am doing with this web application? I just need to put them all together instead of separating them out?

Comment: @NewbyWebProgrammer I updated my question... But yes your css is completely fine!

Comment: @ Zze, Thanks for each and everyone of you all help. My biggest problem was trying to figure out how I would test it using an online mobile device. That solves my problem.

Comment: @NewbyWebProgrammer Firefox's Responsive Design Mode is what I use for all of my interoperability needs. The company I work for previously would buy many test devices until this was released.

Comment: @ Zze, But I downloaded Google Chrome. Can I still test it inside of there? I tried to do what Robert said but Ctrl + Shift + J doesn't open developer console.

Comment: @NewbyWebProgrammer Most definitely you can! The Chrome tool is also very good, I just prefer the firefox tool for the same reason that `@Will` gave in `@Robert I`'s answer: "different pixel densities and network throttling"

Comment: @ Zze, If I wanted to change the text size to fit the size of the screen when it is in portrait form, how could I do that?

Comment: @NewbyWebProgrammer There are actually a few factors which will come into play in regards to that, I would suggest creating a new question for that. Note that there is also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for any code review questions! Also don't forget to accept an answer if any solved your question,.

Answer (score 1):

How to view your website as mobile on desktop:

---

**Chrome**

Just go to your html page and then follow these steps:

```
1. CTRL + SHIFT + J | Open Developer Console

2. CTRL + SHIFT + M (in Developer Console) | Mobile Device View 

3. Use the drop down to select your mobile screen you wish to preview in
```

---

**Firefox** (credit : Will)

```
1. Ctrl + Shift + M (Cmd + Opt + M for OS X)
```

Comment: Firefox has a [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) as well.  `Ctrl + Shift + M` or `Cmd + Opt + M` on OS X. FF wins out in my book. It allows you to test different pixel densities and network throttling directly from that screen.

Comment: @Robert I- I downloaded chrome, and when I open up my HTML page and tried to hit the commands you suggested, nothing happens.

Comment: @NewbyWebProgrammer You have to do step 2 in the dev console.

Comment: @ Zze But when I hold down Ctrl + Shift + M nothing happens.

Comment: @Zze Never mind I forget about the inspect element which will lead you to developer console. Then press  Ctrl + Shift + M